# Why exception occurs in this program?

Tags: java, exception

I have this program and always get the exception in the try catch block as "Something Wrong" in the output. Why is it that the output skips to the catch? Here's the code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;

class pgm {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuffer sa = new StringBuffer();
    StringBuffer n = new StringBuffer();
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    try {
      FileReader fr = new FileReader("1.txt");
      int i;

      while ((i = fr.read()) != -1) {
        n.append((char) i);
      }
      fr.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    String[] lines = String.valueOf(n).split("\n");

    int x = lines.length;
    int count = 1, m = 0;

    try {
      FileWriter fw1 = new FileWriter("1a.txt");
      FileWriter fw2 = new FileWriter("1b.txt");

      String linea = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("1.txt")).get(1);
      sa.append(linea);

      for (int i = 2; count <= x; i++) {
        String lineb = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("1.txt")).get(count);
        String ab = lineb;
        ab = ab.replace("\n", "");
        count++;
        String linec = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("1.txt")).get(count);
        ab += linec;
        sb.append(ab);
        count++;
        m = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
          String lined = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("1.txt")).get(count);
          if (lined == "\n") {
            count++;
            m++;
          } else {
            break;
          }
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
          sa.append("\n");
          sb.append("\n");
        }

        String linee = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("1.txt")).get(count);
        sa.append(linee);
      }

      String sa1 = String.valueOf(sa);
      String sa2 = String.valueOf(sb);

      fw1.write(sa1);
      fw2.write(sa2);
      fw1.close();
      fw2.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Something wrong");
    }
  }
}
```

What is exactly causing the exception in the catch block?

Comment: Add `e.printStackTrace()` in the catch block, and you'll know.

Comment: Please don't use StringBuffer as it was replaced by StringBuilder more than ten years ago.

Comment: If you want to know why it produces an error, perhaps you shouldn't discard your exception as if they didn't happen.

Comment: Reading a file is expensive, I suggest you read the file once and only once. You are reading the entire file an insane number of times, two different way on many lines of code.

Comment: BTW, The first index of a List is `0` not `1`.

Comment: None of the lines will have a new line `\n` inside them by definition.

Comment: Don't use `==` to compare String line this unless you know what you are doing. In particular a line will never be `lined.equals("\n")`

Comment: Thanks, so how do I compare if the line is a newline? Or empty?

Comment: @Rathan if you read a line, it will have the string of the character in the line up to the new line.  This means a blank line will produce a blank/empty String. You can use `"".equals(line)` or even `line.isEmpty()`

Comment: Instead of writing to a buffer which you write to a file, I suggest you write directly to the file.  The code will be shorter and it use less memory.

Comment: Thanks, @PeterLawrey I tried that, I still do get the same error where the count value goes higher than the size of the text file giving the `IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 31, Size 31` where there are 31 lines in text file. I tried line.isEmpty() and "".equals(line) but it still results in same error. Any thoughts?

Comment: Like I said the first index is `0`, if you have `n` rows, the last index is `n-1` not `n`. Change your check to `count < n`

Comment: When you write a program, you should write a little and test it, then write a little more and test it again.  If you write lots of code you can get lots of bugs which makes it really hard to work out what all the problems are.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Thanks, it works perfectly now.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you don't intend to handle or rethrow exceptions, you shouldn't catch them.